# Producer and consumer code don't appear on screen

Tags: c, mutex, semaphore

I have the following code but the producer and consumer code don't appear. It just prints "Exit the program". It's like the consumer and producer functions are never executed. I don't understand why this is happening. Can anyone explain why?
The code is as follows:

```
/* buffer.h */
typedef int buffer_item;
#define BUFFER_SIZE 18

/* main.c */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
/* #include "buffer.h" */


#define RAND_DIVISOR 100000000
#define TRUE 1

/* The mutex lock */
pthread_mutex_t mutex;

/* the semaphores */
sem_t full, empty;

/* the buffer */
buffer_item buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

/* buffer counter */
int counter;

pthread_t tid;       //Thread ID
pthread_attr_t attr; //Set of thread attributes

void *producer(void *param); /* the producer thread */
void *consumer(void *param); /* the consumer thread */

void initializeData()
{

    /* Create the mutex lock */
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);

    /* Create the full semaphore and initialize to 0 */
    sem_init(&full, 0, 0);

    /* Create the empty semaphore and initialize to BUFFER_SIZE */
    sem_init(&empty, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);

    /* Get the default attributes */
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);

    /* init buffer */
    counter = 0;
}

/* Producer Thread */
void *producer(void *param)
{
    buffer_item item;

    while(TRUE)
    {
        /* sleep for a random period of time */
        int rNum = rand() / RAND_DIVISOR;
        sleep(rNum);

        /* generate a random number */
        item = rand();

        /* acquire the empty lock */
        sem_wait(&empty);
        /* acquire the mutex lock */
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

        if (insert_item(item))
            fprintf(stderr, " Producer report error condition\n");
        else
            printf("producer produced %d\n", item);

        /* release the mutex lock */
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        /* signal full */
        sem_post(&full);
    }
}

/* Consumer Thread */
void *consumer(void *param)
{
    buffer_item item;

    while(TRUE) {
        /* sleep for a random period of time */
        int rNum = rand() / RAND_DIVISOR;
        sleep(rNum);

        /* aquire the full lock */
        sem_wait(&full);
        /* aquire the mutex lock */
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        if (remove_item(&item)) {
           fprintf(stderr, "Consumer report error condition\n");
        } else {
            printf("consumer consumed %d\n", item);
        }
        /* release the mutex lock */
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        /* signal empty */
        sem_post(&empty);
    }
}

/* Add an item to the buffer */
int insert_item(buffer_item item)
{
    /* When the buffer is not full add the item
      and increment the counter*/
    if (counter < BUFFER_SIZE) {
        buffer[counter] = item;
        counter++;
        return 0;
    } else { /* Error the buffer is full */
        return -1;
    }
}

/* Remove an item from the buffer */
int remove_item(buffer_item *item)
{
    /* When the buffer is not empty remove the item
      and decrement the counter */
    if (counter > 0) {
        *item = buffer[(counter-1)];
        counter--;
        return 0;
    } else { /* Error buffer empty */
        return -1;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* Loop counter */
    int i;

     /* Verify the correct number of arguments were passed in */
    if(argc != 4) {
        fprintf(stderr, "USAGE:./main.out <INT> <INT> <INT>\n");
    }

    int mainSleepTime = atoi(argv[1]); /* Time in seconds for main to sleep */
    int numProd = atoi(argv[2]); /* Number of producer threads */
    int numCons = atoi(argv[3]); /* Number of consumer threads */

    /* Initialize the app */
    initializeData();

    /* Create the producer threads */
    for(i = 0; i < numProd; i++) {
        /* Create the thread */
        pthread_create(&tid,&attr,producer,NULL);
    }

    /* Create the consumer threads */
    for(i = 0; i < numCons; i++) {
        /* Create the thread */
        pthread_create(&tid,&attr,consumer,NULL);
    }

    /* Sleep for the specified amount of time in milliseconds */
    sleep(mainSleepTime);

    /* Exit the program */
    printf("Exit the program\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: For starters, lose the `sleep()` and try a joining your threads.

Comment: This is a lot of code to ask someone else to debug for you.  Maybe try getting a simpler example working first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to apply different tid's for your threads.

`pthread_t tid1, tid2;`

Then use these tid's:

`pthread_create(&tid1, &attr, producer, NULL);`

`pthread_create(&tid2, &attr, consumer, NULL);`

Lastly, skip the sleep and join the threads.

`pthread_join(tid1, NULL);`

`pthread_join(tid2, NULL);`

I've tested it, and works on my system. Below is the working code in full.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include "buffer.h"


#define RAND_DIVISOR 100000000
#define TRUE 1

/* The mutex lock */
pthread_mutex_t mutex;

/* the semaphores */
sem_t full, empty;

/* the buffer */
buffer_item buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

/* buffer counter */
int counter;

pthread_t tid1, tid2;       //Thread ID
pthread_attr_t attr; //Set of thread attributes

void *producer(void *param); /* the producer thread */
void *consumer(void *param); /* the consumer thread */

void initializeData() {

   /* Create the mutex lock */
   pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);

   /* Create the full semaphore and initialize to 0 */
   sem_init(&full, 0, 0);

   /* Create the empty semaphore and initialize to BUFFER_SIZE */
   sem_init(&empty, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);

   /* Get the default attributes */
   pthread_attr_init(&attr);

   /* init buffer */
   counter = 0;
}

/* Producer Thread */
void *producer(void *param) {
   buffer_item item;

   while(TRUE) {
      /* sleep for a random period of time */
      int rNum = rand() / RAND_DIVISOR;
      sleep(rNum);

      /* generate a random number */
      item = rand();

      /* acquire the empty lock */
      sem_wait(&empty);
      /* acquire the mutex lock */
      pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

      if(insert_item(item)) {
         fprintf(stderr, " Producer report error condition\n");
      }
      else {
         printf("producer produced %d\n", item);
      }
      /* release the mutex lock */
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
      /* signal full */
      sem_post(&full);
   }
}

/* Consumer Thread */
void *consumer(void *param) {
   buffer_item item;

   while(TRUE) {
      /* sleep for a random period of time */
      int rNum = rand() / RAND_DIVISOR;
      sleep(rNum);

      /* aquire the full lock */
      sem_wait(&full);
      /* aquire the mutex lock */
      pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
      if(remove_item(&item)) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Consumer report error condition\n");
      }
      else {
         printf("consumer consumed %d\n", item);
      }
      /* release the mutex lock */
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
      /* signal empty */
      sem_post(&empty);
   }
}

/* Add an item to the buffer */
int insert_item(buffer_item item) {
   /* When the buffer is not full add the item
      and increment the counter*/
   if(counter < BUFFER_SIZE) {
      buffer[counter] = item;
      counter++;
      return 0;
   }
   else { /* Error the buffer is full */
      return -1;
   }
}

/* Remove an item from the buffer */
int remove_item(buffer_item *item) {
   /* When the buffer is not empty remove the item
      and decrement the counter */
   if(counter > 0) {
      *item = buffer[(counter-1)];
      counter--;
      return 0;
   }
   else { /* Error buffer empty */
      return -1;
   }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   /* Loop counter */
   int i;

   /* Verify the correct number of arguments were passed in */
   if(argc != 4) {
      fprintf(stderr, "USAGE:./main.out <INT> <INT> <INT>\n");
   }

   int mainSleepTime = atoi(argv[1]); /* Time in seconds for main to sleep */
   int numProd = atoi(argv[2]); /* Number of producer threads */
   int numCons = atoi(argv[3]); /* Number of consumer threads */

   /* Initialize the app */
   initializeData();

   /* Create the producer threads */
   for(i = 0; i < numProd; i++) {
      /* Create the thread */
      pthread_create(&tid1,&attr,producer,NULL);
    }

   /* Create the consumer threads */
   for(i = 0; i < numCons; i++) {
      /* Create the thread */
      pthread_create(&tid2,&attr,consumer,NULL);
   }

   /* Sleep for the specified amount of time in milliseconds */
   //sleep(mainSleepTime);

   pthread_join(tid1, NULL);
   pthread_join(tid2, NULL);

   /* Exit the program */
   printf("Exit the program\n");
   exit(0);
}
```

Comment: i have done that. atleast now the producer has producer has printed something. however the input and output is as follows: 

  >  $ ./prod 2 4 5
  > producer produced 1085377743
  > producer produced 1085377743
  > producer produced 1085377743
  > producer produced 1085377743
  > producer produced 1191391529
  > producer produced 1191391529
  > producer produced 1191391529
  > producer produced 1191391529

the consumer shows nothing yet. why is this so/ why is the producer printed twice the number of my intended input?

Comment: [jgr@std tmp]$ ./ss 2 4 5
producer produced 1189641421
consumer consumed 1189641421
producer produced 783368690
consumer consumed 783368690
producer produced 1967513926
consumer consumed 1967513926
producer produced 304089172
consumer consumed 304089172
producer produced 521595368
consumer consumed 521595368
producer produced 336465782
consumer consumed 336465782
producer produced 233665123
consumer consumed 233665123

Comment: i dont know why but for some reason the internet connections in this place do not access pastebin. is it possible for you to post the corrected code somewhere else. thanks. ill be waiting :)

Comment: @jgrsomebody tells me that it is blocked ın this area.

Comment: so please post it to some other place or include a link where i can directly download it. thanks

Comment: if you are there, do you please mind resolving this issue as soon as possible? thanks.